# В WebStorm убрать php подсветку?

Tags: php, webstorm, syntax

Установил предложенную highlight подсветку синтаксиса PHP-кода. Хочу убрать. Но не могу найти. Кто знает название?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, что именно вы установили. Если это - некий custom file type (вроде https://github.com/a2net/WebStorm-php-Syntax-Highlight-with-WordPress-functions), он устанавливается в конфигурационную директорию (см. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs), в папку `filetypes`. В таком случае нужно закрыть WebStorm и вручную удалить соответствующий `xml` из папки. Если вы установили некий textmate bundle для подсветки, нужно его удалить из **Settings | Editor | TextMate Bundles**